# Refresh token Vuex before enter in Routing

Tags: vue.js, vuex, laravel-passport

I have an frontend Web app interfaces with API built in Laravel with Passport.

My problem is when I refresh my page (in SPA written with Vuejs/Vuex) I should refresh my token, for refresh session with my Api.

I tried in **main.js** but he problem is that the request is async and the response arrived after routing.

**main.js**

```
if (localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')) {
   store.dispatch('refresh_token').then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
   });
}
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  env,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

The function refresh token, make a call to my Api, and with response set the new token and the new refresh token.
But my problem is that I make this call in this way I can make the first async call in my "dashboard" with old token and then with the new. 
So I've tried in different ways but I don't know if there is a best practice.

So my question is:
Where I should refresh token in Vuejs App with vuex store?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting this in the `mounted` property of you toplevel Vue component. If you have other components that depend on your token being refreshed, you can couple this with a state variable in your store that signals the refresh is completed. For example, with a top level component `App.vue`:

```
...

mounted () {
  store.dispatch('refresh_token')
}

...
```

Adding the state variable to your vueex store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    sessionRefreshed: false
  },
  ..

  mutations: {
    [REFRESH_TOKEN] (state) {
      // existing mutations, and..
      state.sessionRefreshed = true
    },
  },
  ..
  actions: {
    refreshToken ({ commit }) {
      myAsyncFetchToken().then(() => commit(REFRESH_TOKEN))
    },
  }
```

This ensures your entire application is aware of the state of your refresh without forcing it to be synchronous. Then if you have components which require the token to be refreshed, you can show loading widgets, placeholders, etc., and use a watcher to do things when the state changes.

Comment: but if I make this call async, yes I can show loading but if I had a other async call I risk to make a calling with old token and so I will receive a 401, isn't?

Comment: You cant control the order that asynchronous calls complete, by their very definition. It's up to you to structure your application correctly so that calls don't 401, I.e., by using a state variable and watchers.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `router#beforeEach` [guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards)? I use it to figure out if authentication token is stored in a cookie before accessing any "restricted" component. If token is not set I redirect to `/login`.

I realize that my scenario is exactly what you are are asking for but I hope you can use it to augment your implementation.

Comment: interesting, I will try, I make a call in a beforeEach for new fresh token if the token is expired and await te response for call "next()", right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.